# How to close every visible windows with shortcut "Command + W"

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

Working on a simple App that work with a secondary preferences window i found a behavior that i can't understand.

When i open the preferences window if i press Cmd + W i close only the main window.
Is this a standard behavior ? Which is the best way to implement a way to close every windows ?

Comment: You're talking about Command+Option+W. Are you sure that key combo is not working?

Comment: @FrancisMcGrew i'm speaking about "Command + W" under menu "File". Take as example Xcode... when you open preferences whenever you press Cmd+W you close only preference windows...i need closing all windows. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[[NSApp windows] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(close)];`

is a programmatic way to close all windows, but that's really not good design, because the user doesn't expect Command+W to close all windows of an applications. That's what Command+Option+W is for.

If you have a document-based app, you can change your secondary window to an instance of `NSPanel` and then check the "Document Modal" attribute. That way when your document window is closed, the secondary window will close as well.

If it's not a document-based app, you could check window's "Hide on Deactivate" attribute, which will hide the window when the app goes into the background.

Other than that, if you want to "bind" the two windows together I think you'd have to set a NSWindowDelegate and manually maintain their relative visibility state. Does that make sense?